# I cannot install JDK 18 because of "installation in progress: Another Java Installation in progress. You must complete the install.." Error Message

Tags: windows-10, installation, java, openjdk

I was trying to install the latest version of JDK(Java Development Kit) which is version 18.0.1.1 during the installation, my computer suddenly switched off. I switched it on and try the installation again, and the next window that popped up was This:

[image]

I uninstalled the latest version of JDK(JDK 17) which was already installed on my computer, and I tried installing JDK 18, but the message keeps popping up. what surprised me the most was that I tried reinstalling the version 17 and the message still appeared.
I tried some of the solutions(Which was about the deletion of the lock files of Java) the problem still did not get resolved. I tried almost all the recent solutions that I could get from youtube, but the problem still is not resolved. I tried stopping the windows installer from the task manager and from services.mcs but the problem keeps appearing.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot that provides the contents of `C:\Program Files\Java\`, `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\`, `%UserProfile%\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\`, and '%UserProfile%\AppData\LocalLow\Oracle\Java\`.  Since you are using OpenJDK you might have to use some liberties to find the proper folders within `%UserProfile%\AppData\LocalLow\`.  I am specifically attempting to locate the JAVA_INSTALL_FLAG file on your system.

Comment: Have you tried to restart your computer and then try the install again to see if it stops the "other" installation?